# How to override what happens if the video does not play?

Tags: java, android, video, overriding

I wanted to override the alert that is given by default if android device cannot play video. It normally says, "Sorry this video Cannot be played", and then ends the video. I want to return to the main menu when if the video does not play.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
videoView.setOnErrorListener(new OnErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
           //your code
           return true; 
        }
});
```

return true means that you handled the error yourself and android will not do anything so that nasty message wouldn't show up. returning false lets android takes care of error resulting in showing the message.